# Unable To Import 'PIL'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Whenever I add PIL to my imports I always get unable to import 'PIL'. I am In vscode and I have import Pillow
Imports:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw
import io
```

settings.json:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\Pc\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python.exe",
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./Users/Pc/Downloads/ingcog.py/cogs/music.py"],
    "python.jediEnabled": true,
    "python.languageServer": "Jedi"
}
```

I tried doing this stuff all above from researching^

Comment: have you installed the pillow package?

Comment: @derw yes pip install pillow

Comment: What does this have to do with discord.py? Please provide more context.

Comment: When you run `pip install`, is that the version of `pip` that corresponds to the version of `python` you're using in VS?

Comment: Anyway, errors like this certainly occur because you have more than one Python installation on your system, and the one to which you have installed Pillow is not the one that you are using for your program.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel discord.py version: 3.8.5 pillow version 7.2. The error is that to import can't be imported and It makes it so I can't run my bot. yesterday I deleted all py versions I have and I only have 3.8.5 now Another error is: __iter__ returns non-iterator

Comment: Please show a **complete** example that other people could copy and paste, and get the exact result that you do. There's no way we can just *guess* at the bit of code that is causing "another error", nor can we see any of the relevant context for it.

Comment: Why you should use `python -m pip` https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/